# i want button container to be hidden after the hover ends

Tags: css

**i want button container to be hidden after the hover ends, when hover and the overlay appear, i want button container to be visible and when hover ends i want it to be hidden so i tried visiblity: visible but its not working, i also tried (display: none and display:block) and its also not working!

```css
.container{
    width:300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}
img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  
    /* position: absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0px; */



}
.overlay{
    background-color: grey;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 3%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
    /* left:100%; */
    transition: width 0.6s ease-out;

}
.container:hover .overlay{
    width: 100%;
    /* left:0% */
}
.overlay a{
    color: white;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 9px;
}
#button-container{
    visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    margin:70px auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2em;
}
#button-overlay{
    width:10px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top:0;
    transition: width 0.4s;
}

#button-container:hover #button-overlay{
    
    width: 100%;
}

#button-container:hover #button-container{
visibility: visible;}
#button-container:hover #learn-more{
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class ="container"> 
       <img src="3.jpeg" alt="">
       <div class="overlay">
           <a href="#" class="social">facebook</a>
           <a href="#" class="social">twitter</a>
           <a href="#" class="social">instagram</a>
           <div id="button-container">
            <a id="learn-more" >learn more</a>
            <div id="button-overlay"></div>
           </div>
          
       </div>

       
    </div>
    
</body>
```

Comment: Hi can you try and clarify what you want please, can't quite understand

Comment: i want button container to be hidden after the hover ends, when hover and the overlay appear, i want button container to be visible and when hover ends i want it to be hidden so i tried visiblity: visible but its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try scaling your button-container from 0 to 1 with transition delay.

```css
.container{
    width:300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}
img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  
    /* position: absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0px; */



}
.overlay{
    background-color: grey;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 3%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
    /* left:100%; */
    transition: width 0.6s ease-out;

}
.container:hover .overlay{
    width: 100%;
    /* left:0% */
}
.overlay a{
    color: white;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 9px;
}
.container:hover #button-container{
    transform: scale(1);
}
#button-container{
    width: 120px;
    transform: scale(0);
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    margin:70px auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2em;
    transform-origin: left top;
    trnasition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 250ms;
}
#button-overlay{
    width:10px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top:0;
    transition: width 0.4s;
}

#button-container:hover #button-overlay{
    
    width: 100%;
}

#button-container:hover #button-container{
visibility: visible;}
#button-container:hover #learn-more{
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class ="container"> 
       <img src="3.jpeg" alt="">
       <div class="overlay">
           <a href="#" class="social">facebook</a>
           <a href="#" class="social">twitter</a>
           <a href="#" class="social">instagram</a>
           <div id="button-container">
            <a id="learn-more" >learn more</a>
            <div id="button-overlay"></div>
           </div>
          
       </div>

       
    </div>
    
</body>
```

Comment: @emyy96 if my answer has resolved your issue please accept the solution. Let me know if you still have any challenges with your problem.